# Angular generic function handler not update component properties

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component that has 2 checkboxes that in each change event - aside text is changed.

I want to avoid double code so I created a function that receive two arguments the chackbox model and text to change but it seems that the value are passed by value.

Is it possible to pass it by reference? if not - what it the best-practice solution?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="aa" [(ngModel)]="checkboxOne" (change)="genericOnChange(checkboxOne,textOne)">  
{{textOne}}
```

```
<input type="checkbox" id="nn" [(ngModel)]="checkboxTwo" (change)="genericOnChange(checkboxTwo,textTwo)">
 {{textTwo}}
```

```
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }

checkboxOne = false;
checkboxTwo = false;
textOne = '';
textTwo = '';
ngOnInit() {}


genericOnChange(checkboxModel,componentProperty){
if(checkboxModel){
    componentProperty ="pew pew pew!"
}
else{
   componentProperty ="laser gun off!"

  }
 }
}
```

[Please see stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-basic-tutorial-96slrt?file=app%2Fabout%2Fabout.component.html) (about.component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s passing the value because there isn’t a reference, it’s a primitive (you don't have a pointer like you would in C). You could create an object, or you could pass the variable name in as a string and do:
`this[myVariable]`. I would recommend the former (an object), as you could have a checkbox object with both checkboxes as properties:

```
checkboxes = {one: true, two: false}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper object around your checkboxProperties, and pass that reference as a single parameter to your `genericOnChange(...)` function

```
  genericOnChange(chk:CheckboxProperties){
    if(chk.checked){
        chk.name ="pew pew pew!"
    }
    else{
       chk.name ="laser gun off!"
    }
  }
```

Now you are modifying a property of the object, and not a primitive string.  Your changes will be reflected on the template as you are expecting.

Full example below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-basic-tutorial-r7eaup?file=app%2Fabout%2Fabout.component.ts